# not able to assign `boost::assign::list_of` to `static const std::vector`

Tags: c++, vector, boost, c++03

I am using C++ 03, previously I have code:

`static const std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>> a = boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1)) std::make_pair(2,2));`

and it worked.

Now I need to add an If block and in different cases `a` needs to be different values, so I have:

```
static const std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t>> a;
if (xxx){
    a = boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1)) std::make_pair(2,2));
}
else{
    a = boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1)) std::make_pair(3,3));
}
```

and I got `error:ambiguious overload for operator= ..........`
how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide the full error message?

Comment: You declare variable `a` as `const` yet you try to assign it later. Isn't that a fundamental problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at your error message you'll probably find mention of not being able to convert to `const`. As `a` is `const` you can't assign to it. You need to either make `a` non-`const` or you need to initialise it on assignment. You can do this either with a ternary:

```
static const std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> > a = xxx ?
    boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1))(std::make_pair(2,2)) :
    boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1))(std::make_pair(3,3));
```

Or by using a function:

```
std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> > make_a()
{
    if (xxx)
    {
        return boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1))(std::make_pair(2,2));
    }
    else
    {
        return boost::assign::list_of(std::make_pair(1,1))(std::make_pair(3,3));
    }
}
static const std::vector<std::pair<uint16_t, uint16_t> > a = make_a();
```